# Mass sending of scheduled emails with date

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api, mime

Basically, I have 300 email addresses which I have to send an email on the person's birthday. It's kind of a happy birthday email.

I have the data in an excel and I get python to read it and also send the mail. But now what I need is to create the emails with a send date.

Basically Python has to create scheduled emails and that if I do not know how to do it. I'm using `gmailAPI`. Someone can help me?

```
mail = {
        'message': {
            'raw': raw_string,
            'internalDateSource': 'dateHeader',
            'payload': {
                'headers': [
                    {'name': 'Date', 'value': send_time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

this is only a part of the code. I tried this but nothing.

Comment: What columns do you have in excel? And do you only need to send the same happy birthday message? Please provide more information.

Comment: Thats dosent matter. The thing is that the gmail must be scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the Gmail API doesn't have a scheduling feature. I'd recommend creating a cron of some sort that runs your code every day and checks for emails that need to be sent out that day.